# Address of a pointer vs Reference to a pointer

Tags: c++

I wrote this code:

```
int* p = new int(7);
std::cout << p << std::endl;    //output: 0096FAB4
std::cout << &p << std::endl;    //output: 0096FA90
```

Why is the output diferent?

Comment: `&p` is the address of `p`, not a reference to a pointer.

Comment: The *value* of `p` is different than the *address* of `p`.

Comment: Because first cout <<p  prints content of P and second cout << &p prints address of p .

Comment: The same reason you get a different result if `p` is declared as `int`.

Comment: Ok. That means that a pointer holds an address but also have a adress of his own, not one and the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each object in C++ is represented by the address of the physical location of this object. If you create an address type int *p = new int(7); so when you call std::cout << p << std::endl; it will output the address of the cell in memory, where the address of number 7 is located. 
And when you call std::cout << &p << std::endl; so it will output the physical address of cell in memory, where the number 7 is located.

To conclude:

- //output: 0096FAB4 is the address of address of the integer 7
- //output: 0096FA90 is the physical address of the integer 7

Example:

- If we look in the memory by the address 0096FAB4 we will see 0096FA90
- If we look in the memory by the address 0096FA90 we will see 00000007

Comment: Absolutely and completely wrong. There is no place in memory where `number 7 is located`.

Comment: @SergeyA : can you prove your point of view or give your explanation?